# What does it mean with 1+ Helpful flags in a person's own profile?

Tags: discussion

When I'm viewing a user's profile (i.e.: [kingkool68](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2744/kingkool68)), even a Moderator's profile (like [Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/847/rarst)), it's not there. But when in my profile I can see:

```
helpful flags   21
```

Eventually I got that, it's the number of *flagged* Q or A or Comments that grabbed Moderators' attention correctly.

But I wonder:

- Why the count is important?
- While it's not visible to others, then why the statistics is important to a user personally?
- Does it lead to a badge or some reputation up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the count is important?

If I am not mistaken the flag allowance (how much you can flag in a day) is tied to that stat.

> Does it lead to a badge or some reputation up?

There are two badges for 80 ([Deputy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/badges/67/deputy)) and 500 ([Marshal](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/marshal)) helpful flags.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it lead to a badge or some reputation up?

You get the gold [Marshal badge](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/70/marshal).

And in case there's a community election, you'll as well be able to show people/voters if you're really interested in moderating the community.